# Finding all links between IDs in SQL

Tags: sql, database, teradata, recursive-query

If I have a data source that contains pairs of IDS like the following:

| ID_1 | ID_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 0002 |
| NULL | 0002 |
| 0002 | 0002 |
| 0002 | 0003 |
| 0003 | 0002 |
| 0004 | 0003 |

this table can contain ID_1 and ID_2 that are different values, the same values or null values and they can be in the table with values both ways round (0002,0003) and (0003,0002)

How do I create a query that would output all combinations of pairs that are directly or indirectly linked?

i.e. 0001 links to 0002 directly
but also to 0003 via 0002 and then to 0004 via 0003

Comment: Are the links directed or just unordered pairings? In other words, if you had just the two rows (0001,0002) and (0003,0002) to start with, would the result include (0001,0003)?

Comment: So they are unordered pairings. In this example I am trying to get both 0001,0002 and 0001,0003 in the output

Comment: And what about 0001, 0004? in your question you said *and then to 0004 via 0003*

Comment: Yes, also 0001, 0004. I am trying to get all possible combinations where they are linked directly or indirectly:

0001,0002
0001,0003
0001,0004
0002,0001
0002,0003
0002,0004
etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a recursive query using `least` and `greatest` functions to avoid *infinite recursion*. In your sample data, an *id_x* is connected to *id_y* and it's possible to have *id_y* connected to *id_x*, i.e. (1, 2) and (2, 1); using `least` and `greatest` (respectively) will give us only one pair of the two pairs (1, 2).

```
with recursive cte(id_1, id_2) as
(
  select least(id_1, id_2) id_1, greatest(id_1, id_2) id_2 
  from table_name
  where id_1 is not null and id_2 is not null
  union all
  select cte.id_1, t.id_2
  from (
  select least(id_1, id_2) id_1, greatest(id_1, id_2) id_2
  from table_name
  ) t join cte
  on t.id_1 = cte.id_2
  where t.id_1 <> t.id_2 -- to avoid infinite recursion where id_1 = id_2
)
select distinct id_1, id_2 from cte
order by id_1
```

[see a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/329lk6Wc) on MySQL

Comment: Thank you. This did give me what I wanted. To get all combinations I added: 
`select distinct id_1, id_2 from cte union select distinct id_2, id_1 from cte `